# IIS site don't get CSS and JS in https (it is in http)

Tags: css, iis, https

I have worked IIS site which has worked in HTTPS. Something break and now when i try to get it in https site looks like that without CSS styles. I see in source and CSS and JS files try to open as http (which get 404 error when I try to open it), but when i try to open it via https everything work. How to "force" these to open these files via https? URL rewrite rule, but how?

Thanks for help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

This what you experiencing is "mixed content blocking". It occures when you reach website via https but some elements are via http.

To resolve the problem you should configure http to https redirection.
You can find 'how to' here: https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/

Also make sure that you don't hardcoded links to application elements via http in app code (if yes then change to https).